# XPath for following-sibling and self node?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

As in the code:

```
<body>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div><span>6</span></div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</body>
```

Find preceding-sibling and self node?

Need to get:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div><span>6</span></div>
```

I tried to write like this:

```
//div[span]/self::node()[self::node() and self::node()/preceding-sibling::div]
```

...but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//div[span or following-sibling::div[span]]
```

will select all `div` elements with a `span` child or that are siblings before such a `div` element:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div><span>6</span></div>
```

as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, but probably less efficient :

```
//span[parent::div]/following::div[1]/preceding::div
```

Select the preceding `div` elements of the first `div` which follows the `span` element.

Output :

```
Element='<div>1</div>'
Element='<div>2</div>'
Element='<div>3</div>'
Element='<div>4</div>'
Element='<div>5</div>'
Element='<div>
   <span>6</span>
</div>'
```